# Is it possible to prevent execution of further tasks in locust TaskSequence if some task has failed?

Tags: locust

For example i have the following class. How i can prevent execution of `get_entity` task if `create_entity` task was not executed?

```
class MyTaskSequence(TaskSequence):

    @seq_task(1)
    def create_entity(self):
        self.round += 1
        with self.client.post('/entities', json={}, catch_response=True) as resp:
            if resp.status_code != HTTPStatus.CREATED:
                resp.failure()
                # how to stop other tasks for that run?

        self.entity_id = resp.json()['data']['entity_id']

    @seq_task(2)
    def get_entity(self):
        # It is being always executed, 
        # but it should not be run if create_entity task failed
        resp = self.client.get(f'/entities/{self.entity_id}')
        ...
```

I found `TaskSet.interrupt` method in documentation, but does not allow to cancel root TaskSet. I tried to make parent TaskSet for my task sequence, so `TaskSet.interrupt` works.

```
class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):
    tasks = {MyTaskSequence: 10}
```

But now i see that all results in ui are cleared after i call `interrupt`!

I just need to skip dependent tasks in this sequence. I need the results.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is just to use a single @task with multiple requests inside it. Then, if a request fails just do a `return` after resp.failure()

Answer (score 0):

Might `self.interrupt()` be what you are looking for?

See https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/writing-a-locustfile.html#interrupting-a-taskset for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `on_start(self):` which runs once whenever a locust created, it can set a global which can be checked whether the locust executes the tasks

```py
class MyTaskSequence(TaskSequence):
    entity_created = false

    def on_start(self):
        self.round += 1
        with self.client.post('/entities', json={}, catch_response=True) as resp:
            if resp.status_code != HTTPStatus.CREATED:
                self.entity_created = true
                resp.failure()

        self.entity_id = resp.json()['data']['entity_id']

    @seq_task(2)
    def get_entity(self):
        if self.entity_created:
            resp = self.client.get(f'/entities/{self.entity_id}')
            ...
```